# How to calculate sum of JSON formatted data using mysql substring_index in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have 3 rows of each employee of monthly salary details for the month of April ,May ,june. Payslip_earnings column saved details in the format of JSON  like

```
{"basicpay":40000,"hra":16000,..etc }
```

I can able to get sum of json data variables while execute query separately in phpmyadmin using

```
sum(substring_index ( substring_index (payslip_earnings,'{"basicpay":',-1),'," ',1) ) as basic.
```

Facing blank page Error/syntax error while select basic inside in codeiginter Model Page

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT payslip.payslip_empcode, 
         sum(substring_index ( substring_index (payslip_earnings,'{"basicpay":',-1),'," ',1) ) as basic
         FROM payslip LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_official_master ON
         payslip.payslip_empcode=employee_official_master.employee_code 
         WHERE payslip.payslip_fyear = '2018' and  
         payslip.payslip_empcode IN ('MAR015','MAR010') AND 
         ( payslip_month = 'April' OR payslip_month = 'May' OR payslip_month = 'June') 
GROUP BY payslip.payslip_empcode "
           );
```

How to achieve the same in codeigniter model page   ?

Comment: Watch your quotes, `"SELECT... '{"basicpay":'`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. kerbholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this One..
$colname  = '{"basicpay":' ;            
         $seperator = ',';  
         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT payslip.payslip_empcode, 
         sum(substring_index (substring_index (payslip.payslip_earnings,'".$colname."',-1),'".$seperator."',1) ) as basicpay
         FROM payslip LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_official_master ON
         payslip.payslip_empcode=employee_official_master.employee_code 
         WHERE payslip.payslip_fyear = '2018' and  
         payslip.payslip_empcode IN ('MAR015','MAR010') AND 
         ( payslip_month = 'April' OR payslip_month = 'May' OR payslip_month = 'June') 
GROUP BY payslip.payslip_empcode "
           );
```